# ESGF `wget` scripts incorrectly generating; linking to a random unrelated file

Tags: wget, cdo-climate

About half the time when I click on `WGET script` following a CMIP6 data search on the ESGF (LLNL node), I get a `wget` script that only points to one, unrelated file. It's always the same one, too. Here's the relevant line that shows up in each `wget` file:

```
download_files="$(cat <<EOF--dataset.file.url.chksum_type.chksum
'famipc5_ne120_v0.3_00001_01_198001_198401_climo.nc' 'http://esgf.anl.gov/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/ACME/climo/amip/v0_3/atm/mon/native/ne120/ens1/famipc5_ne120_v0.3_00001_01_198001_198401_climo.nc' 'SHA256' 'e5040c5df9d080437418943f02a41e84712dbe1c4a69982447712d7c7334241d'
EOF--dataset.file.url.chksum_type.chksum
)"
```

This happens with a wide variety of datasets. Here's one file where that happens, for example:
`CMIP6.CMIP.CCCma.CanESM5.amip.r1i1p1f1.day.pr.gn`

I've been searching for a reason, so far without success. A workaround is to hit the "download HTML" button 1000 times for each individual needed file instead (or set up a Globus endpoint for the files where that's possible), but it's very inconvenient and doesn't provide the functionality of a bash script.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? Is there some sort of limit to how many `wget` scripts an ESGF user can generate per day and these are downloaded as placeholders afterwards instead?

Grateful for any insight!

PS: I apologize for the `cdo` tag; I know this isn't a `cdo` problem, but it's hard to find relevant tags for this, and I figured that community may know what's up.

Comment: You will have to make this reproducible, showing how you generated the wget script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a browser issue. Repeating the search with chrome fixed it.

(Also that stack overflow may have not been the right venue to post this question; but I want this to be searchable *somewhere* at least)